# how to simply execute the values of a key where the value is a list of elements and each element execute should execute in parallel in jenkins groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have as json as below
{

"data1":["apple","mango","grapes"],
"data2":["kiwi","papaya"]

}

I wanted to execute as

```
node{
stage1 {

// Here I need to get values of key ("data1") and execute each element of the list in parallel
}

stage2 {
// Here I need to get values of key ("data2") and execute each element of the list in parallel
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the `parallel` takes a `Map<String, Closure>` (where the string is the label for the step which is shown in the log and the closure is the action which is performed). In your case you have a list and want to transform it into a map. You can do this with a for loop or use the [collectEntries](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.8.9/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collectEntries(java.util.Map,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) function.

```
data = [data1: ["apple","mango","grapes"], data2: ["kiwi","papaya"]]

node {
    stage("stage1"){
        parallel data.data1.collectEntries{fruit -> [fruit, { println("processing $fruit") }]}
    }
}
```

If you run this it will output:

```
[apple]  processing apple
[mango]  processing mango
[grapes] processing grapes
```

Comment: Thanks but my data is like below  data = {data1: ["apple","mango","grapes"], data2: ["kiwi","papaya"]}

Comment: I don't see the difference. Is you data a json string? In that case just use this to parse it into a groovy map https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace